# Passing data(ArrayList and Int) from Adapter to AlertDialog

Tags: android, serializable, dialogfragment

I have CustomDialog class that extends DialogFragment. I want to get ArrayList from my Adapter. I Have this Exception  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.Serializable android.os.Bundle.getSerializable(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference when I try to run.

```
holder.choisirButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int positionselected = menuItem.getId();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("menuItemList", menuItemList);
        bundle.putInt("positionselected", positionselected);
        FragmentActivity activity = (FragmentActivity) (context);
        FragmentManager fm = activity.getFragmentManager();
        ComplementFragment alertDialog = new ComplementFragment();
        alertDialog.show(fm, "fragment_alert");
    }
});

public class ComplementFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ArrayList<MenuItem> menuItemsList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_layout, container);

        menuItemList = (ArrayList<MenuItem>) getArguments().getSerializable("menuItemList");
        int selectedPosition = getArguments().getInt("positionselected");
        MenuItem menuItem = menuItemList.get(selectedPosition);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You many need to cast serializable while putting the array in bundle. You can check the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40689889/null-object-reference-error-while-passing-a-serializable-object-to-fragment). OR you can use a method to create custom dialog and receive the array as parameter in that method. Check the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9956462/5590249). Although the best way of solving it is using parceable. Details about using parcelable can be found from [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/transfer-data-between-activities-with-android-parcelable/) and [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable). For using parcelable to pass data to fragments, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33649155/5590249) answer. I hope my answer is helpful.